# Deletion of duplicate node in Linked List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Program to delete all the occurence of duplicate nodes from the linked list is written below. In the code, we are return new head of linked list after deletion as "dummy.next" but in starting dummy is pointing towards head so if we delete head, then dummy.next should also return the deleted node then why is it returning the new head?
Example input : 1 1 1 2 3 
Output:2 3

```
class Solution {
public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
    dummy.next = head;
    ListNode n = dummy;
    while (n.next != null && n.next.next != null) {
        if (n.next.val == n.next.next.val) {
            int duplicate = n.next.val;
            while (n.next != null && n.next.val == duplicate) {
                n.next = n.next.next;
            }
        } else {
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

}

P.S- I do not want to return the deleted node, I want to return the new head and I just want to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the consecutive nodes with the same value or the nodes with the same value across the whole list?

Comment: Can you try with HashTable<int,int> where <Value, Count>. You need to check whether key is exist. if yes, increase count else add it with 1 count in hashtable. at end, which ever, key's count is more than 1, dont add them in your list. after that, just put null in the next of last node. Complexity: o(n), space: o(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with a simpler example and you'll understand. Consider a list with just 2 nodes.

```
1  -> 1*
^
Head
```

(`*` is to denote visual distinction)

You create a new dummy node and point its next to Head

```
0  ->  1  ->  1*
^      ^
dummy  Head
```

Then, you start your iteration from dummy (by doing `n = dummy`)

```
0    ->  1  ->  1*
^        ^    
n,dummy  Head
```

You enter the loop and you enter the if condition. The fact that you're changing `n`'s `next`, also changes `dummy`'s `next`.

```
0    ->  1*  <- 1
^               ^
n,dummy         Head
```

In this way, you keep moving `dummy`'s `next` as long as the consecutive values are same. Once you encounter a different value, then you march `n` forward and leave `dummy.next` pointing to the head.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Duplicate Nodes From Unsorted List: https://github.com/jayesh-tanna/coding-problem-solution/blob/master/DataStructures/SinglyLinkList/RemoveDuplicateNodesFromUnsortedList.java

Remove Duplicates From Sorted List: https://github.com/jayesh-tanna/coding-problem-solution/blob/master/DataStructures/SinglyLinkList/RemoveDuplicatesFromSortedList.java